# How do I enable link time optimization (LTO) with CMake?

Tags: cmake, lto

I have the most recent cmake build and trying all build configurations (Debug, MinSizeRel, RelWithDebugInfo, Release, General) I see nowhere (text search) in generated makefiles the string `-lto`, so or the functionality is still not present, or it requires manual intervertion (in that case a text search for LTO or Link time optimization) over the documentation gives no result, so I see nowhere in official documentation a way to enable LTO.

Is there any way to enable LTO "globally" (for all compilers) without specifying manually flags that could be at worst supported only by GCC?

Comment: Nowadays, CMake do not have a crossplatform support for LTO. You ought to add it by yourself by adding desired compile options and using corresponding tools (like `gcc-ar`, `gcc-nm` and `gcc-ranlib` instead of defaults) because binutils, AFAIK, nowadays is not completely ready for this as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit: as of 28 October, 2015 on CMake IRC

```
jcelerier | I have a question about INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
jcelerier | it sounds like it should enable -flto on gcc
+ngladitz | jcelerier: its only implemented for the intel compiler
jcelerier | ngladitz: ah, okay
jcelerier | are there other switches for pgo / lto ?
jcelerier | or must it be done by hand ?
+ngladitz | there currently is no first class support otherwise
```

Related CMake issue: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15245

---

CMake has the `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` property on targets, which sounds like it may enable LTO on some platforms.

Link : http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.html

To enable it on a target MyLib :

```
add_library(MyLib ...)
...
set_property(TARGET MyLib PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION True)
```

Comment: cmake documentation is verly lacky, just for completeness how someone is supposed to enable that flag in a Cmake script?

Comment: @darioOO Added to the answer

Comment: This seems like the CMake way to do it. However when testing on Debian Jessie with CMake 3.0 and gcc 4.9.2 and clang 3.5.0 this did not seem to activate any lto related compiler flags. :-/

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 106):

Good news! **CMake v3.9** finally ***supports LTO***.

---

## Example

Here's an example code to show how it works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.4)

include(CheckIPOSupported)
check_ipo_supported(RESULT supported OUTPUT error)

add_executable(example Example.cpp)

if( supported )
    message(STATUS "IPO / LTO enabled")
    set_property(TARGET example PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
else()
    message(STATUS "IPO / LTO not supported: <${error}>")
endif()
```

For GCC this adds `-flto -fno-fat-lto-objects` to the targets compile commands.

---

## Checking Compiler Support

The Module [***CheckIPOSupported***](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIPOSupported.html#module:CheckIPOSupported) provides checking whether *interprocedural optimization **(IPO/LTO)*** is supported by the compiler or not:

```
check_ipo_supported([RESULT <result>] [OUTPUT <output>]
                    [LANGUAGES <lang>...])
```

If no arguments is passed (= `check_ipo_supported()`) an error is raised to indicate it's not supported, otherwise the `result` variable is set to either `YES` or `NO`. More details are described in the documentation of the module.

---

### Enabling LTO

LTO is enabled either for a ***single target*** or as ***default*** for all targets.

#### LTO for a single target

To enable LTO for a target set [**`INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.html) to `TRUE`. This is done by the [**`set_property()`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) command:

```
set_property(TARGET name-target-here
             PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
```

#### LTO as default

It's possible to enable LTO per default by setting [**`CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.html) to `TRUE`:

```
set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
```

This will enable `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` for all targets created *after* this line. Those created before are not affected.

---

#### See also

- [CMake issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15245)
- [Related Pull Requests](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=merged&label_name%5B%5D=area%3Aipo)

Comment: For LTO as default: "*for all targets created after this line*", this is supposed to affect child projects too (e.g. from `add_subdirectory`) right?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Why the <beep> does a make tool need to support a particular compiler option?!?!

Comment: I found that CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION  works more reliably than setting INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION for individual targets, and mixing targets with and without LTO does not seem to work well. With Clang, I had link errors when linking LTO-ed libraries into a non-LTO target. Also, with MSVC setting LTO for targets individually will make the linker complain about it being incompatible with incremental linking.

Comment: Why the heck do I have to check for support myself? Edit: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/policy/CMP0069.html

Comment: So it's easier to just set the flags myself which I do anyway, and I have full control.

Comment: To give the rightful rant of @Trass3r some context: setting the variable is not enough. In their deep wisdom the cmake devs have decided that the project also needs to manually add a check for LTO into the project's cmakefile. Only if that's there you may enable LTO with `-DCMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION=TRUE`. Of course nobody does that and you are forced to edit the project files...

Comment: What's up with C++ programmers and build system (generators) they produce with an attitude that causes everything to look like they were tasked with half-assing something but they went ahead and half-assed the half-assing? 21 years of development, and all we have is some basic handwritten Makefile-tier if else to test whether compiler can into LTO, really now? Should I just write [my own](https://xkcd.com/927/) Makefile generator at this point if I want something to just work?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, according to source code there are no support for LTO for gcc/clang compilers. They have some support for Intel compiler only.

I have some grep output for cmake 3.4.3:

```
grep -HiR 'INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION' *
Help/manual/cmake-properties.7.rst:  
/prop_dir/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG
Help/manual/cmake-properties.7.rst:  
/prop_dir/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
Help/manual/cmake-properties.7.rst:  
/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG
Help/manual/cmake-properties.7.rst:  
/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
Help/prop_dir/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.rst:INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
Help/prop_dir/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG.rst:INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_<CONFIG    
Help/prop_dir/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG.rst:This is a
per-configuration version of INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.
Help/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.rst:INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
Help/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG.rst:INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_<CONFIG    
Help/prop_tgt/INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_CONFIG.rst:This is a
per-configuration version of INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION.
Modules/Platform/Linux-Intel.cmake:    # INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
Source/cmCommonTargetGenerator.cxx: 
if(this->GetFeatureAsBool("INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION"))
Source/cmGeneratorTarget.cxx:          
"INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION", config))
Source/cmMakefileLibraryTargetGenerator.cxx: 
if(this->GetFeatureAsBool("INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION") &&
Tests/IPO/CMakeLists.txt:set_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY
INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION 1)
```

As you can see we have only Intel platform module.

So I have created feature request for this extremely useful feature: https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15939

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this problem again in a project where I had to include the cmake configuration of an immutable subproject, it seems the most forceful way to enable LTO is adding this before defining any targets or including anything:

```
set(CMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0069 NEW)
set(CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
```

This enables LTO and shuts up CMAKE even if later included projects did not handle LTO via `CheckIPOSupported` themselves.

Answer (score -2):

At the moment both gcc and clang support lto.
(See: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html
)
You can enable it in via cmake: 
set (CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION True)
However you need to have version cmake >= 3.9, and I think may be set some policy and check whether LTO is supported by the compiler / toolchain ( check CMAKE_IPO_AVAILABLE and throw error otherwise)

And set flags for gcc/clang ( -flto and -ffat-lto-files for fcc >4.7 or -flto=full/thin for clang)